# CSS Color Doesn't Load for Button

Tags: html, css, colors

Can somebody assist with why the buttons on the page below don't render the background color correctly? The background-color property appears to be set correctly but I'm wondering if there's a conflict with another CSS file my template is using. Any advice?

http://www.chrisboulasphotography.com/store/ferrari-owners-manuals

Comment: What color is the background supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

This gradient (defined in [/wp-content/w3tc/min/1088176c.f6146a.css](http://www.chrisboulasphotography.com/wp-content/w3tc/min/1088176c.f6146a.css) on line 379) is clobbering the `background` property...

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #F0F0F0 2%, #FAFAFA 51%);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I commented that portion out and it doesn't appear to be reflecting a change where the button color doesn't match the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Alex answered this perfectly right. Using Firefox with Firebug I have been able to disactivate the css line he suggested and it seems that the background color of your buttons appears again.

Have you emptied you cache to check if it's not your browser who has kept the old css in memory?

Comment: Thanks! Got it all taken care of now. You were right, had to refresh the cache.